# How do I retrieve an XML file from FTP to consume with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ftp

I need to retrieve a file from an FTP site, and store it on my server to be able to load and parse it with javascript. It's a dynamic file, so I need this to happen when it's requested, or at given intervals, so that the XML is always up to date.

I'm not experienced with PHP, so don't hesitate to dumb it down for me--or feel free to offer other suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share anything that you have tried with us.

Comment: haha I've tried asking the question--I'm not sure where to start

Comment: Start with the basics - http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Comment: Up-vote for a perfect starting point! I've got it up and running. Thanks!